# angular js nd javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

How to open excel sheet click on button .i write the code of this but getting problem

```
function openFile(strFilePath)
    {
    var objExcel;
            //Create EXCEL object
    objExcel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    objExcel.Visible = true;
    objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath, false, false);
}
```

the problem is ActiveXObject is not defined. I tried with more code but not getting solution.plz give me any solution for this .

Comment: Note that ActiveXObject is supported in Internet Explorer only.

Comment: I know but what should I do for this any solution and not supported in Internet Explorer also .i need to.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery we can do

```
function parseExcel(str) {
if (str == null) return null;
if ($.trim(str) == "") return createDocument();

var dom = str;
if ($.browser.msie) {
    dom = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    dom.async = "false";
    dom.loadXML(str);
}
else if (typeof (DOMParser) != "undefined") {
   //.. 
   we can try other browser compatable code
}
```

This link may help you https://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/jWAJ7/

Comment: actually, i tried this code. i want to directly click on button open excel sheet .from this code is doing  download excel sheet file which is i dont want